# Format blank cells based on text in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, formatting, conditional-formatting

I would like to apply conditional formatting to a sheet, however, cant figure out the right formula.

The formatting would only apply to BLANK cells in columns S to AT based on text in in column I.

so if I1 = "live", any BLANK cells in rows S to AT need to be highlighted in yellow to draw attention. 
This needs to be applied to the whole sheet which is about 1000 rows

Comment: S to AT are columns not rows.  You refer to them as rows in the 3rd paragraph

Answer (score 0):

Start by selection S1 and chosing to create a new Consitional Formatting rule then chose to base it on a formula. The formula you want is

```
=IF(AND(S1="",$I1="live"),TRUE,FALSE)
```

This works by always looking in Column I for "live" and then looking to see if S1 is blank. By having S1 without any $ symbols is is fully dynamic, whilst the reference to column I is static for the column but dynamic for the row.

You can then set your formatting choices before applying setting to rule to apply to the entire area required.